# windows phone 7 - phonegap stops jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova, cors

This is my first question here, so sorry if I break some rule. I know this can seem a duplicate, but every answer I found here and on the web gave me no result at all.

I'm developing a multiplatform, multipage, SOAP-XML web-service based app for iOS, Android and Windows Phone. Everything alright with iOS and Android, but when porting to Windows Phone 7/8 I've run into this nasty problem: any call to jQuery.ajax (internal and external) and derivatives ($.load, $.get) starts but apparently never receives an answer.

Currently I'm using jQuery 2.0.2, Cordova 2.5.0, and Weinre for the debug. I cut off jQuery mobile because of the complexity of the code it generated (so no use for $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages).

This is my code of one internal ajax call for navigation

```
$("#base_page").load(
    thePage,
    function () {
        console.log("------------ loadPage: ", thePage, " loaded");
        $(document).trigger("pageload", [thePage]);
    }
);
```

This gives me no answer at all.

And here's the code of one external ajax call for WS data mining

```
$.ajax({
    url: soapURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: createSOAPRequest(soapWS, soapParams),
    contentType: "text/xml; charset='utf-8'",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        console.log("•••••••••••••• ready to send ajax");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', soapURL);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("•••••••••••••• error");
        navigator.notification.alert(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(theXML) {
        console.log("•••••••••••••• success");
        console.log(theXML);
        // .......... building-page code
    }
});
```

This writes in the console "•••••••••••••• ready to send ajax" then absolutely nothing more.

I think I've tried all I could find here and on other sources in the web. If I don't miss something, I tried

- $.support.cors = true as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989509/windows-phone-7-no-post-data-for-jquery-ajax-calls?lq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311973/cannot-covert-html5-javascript-jqueryajax-app-with-phonegap)
- any combination of cache: false, crossDomain: true, xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
- deactivating the win.XMLHttpRequest parts of the Cordova code as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031968/phonegap-for-windows-phone-jquery-ajax-callback-not-executed)
- every local url description, absolute or relative, simple (only the page) or full path (starting with /www or /app/www or even the complete fool MS protocol)
- URIs are whitelisted in config.xml

but to no avail. JSONP is not an option, since the server fires an error with the callback value.

The problem is I never receive any error/success message (so it's different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie)), as if no data were coming out of the WebService. Everything's working like a charm in the other OSs, so I'm sure WebService calls are correct.

As a desperate solution, I've already managed to rewrite the internal calls via XMLHttpRequest object, and that part is now ok. But before rewriting the more complex POST calls to the WebService I'm wondering if there's any way to restore the (easier and already working) jQuery.ajax functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your options for cross-domain requests are JSONP, CORS (through the server-side "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`" header, or a native http request through cordova. The first two options require that the server is willing to play ball with your application.